# Should I use separate WSGI servers for async frameworks like aiohttp and sanic?

Tags: python, asynchronous, wsgi, aiohttp, sanic

I have experience with Flask and Falcon, for running sites in prod I used separate http-servers like uwsgi\unicorn. But do I need it for modern for Sanic? By the docs  it can server own files pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I recently answered this same question [over on the Sanic community forums](https://community.sanicframework.org/t/gunicorn-uwsgi-vs-build-in-http-server/47/2?u=ahopkins).

The short answer is **no**. You do not need to use gunicorn or another similar server in production. Sanic `app.run` can be used and works well. So, the question then becomes *should I use...*.

For this, and to reiterate my answer from the forums, I would recommend that you look at your intended use and determine what makes the most sense.

Yes, [Sanic can serve static files](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/static_files.html). If you are doing something small and lightweight, then perhaps a single instance of Sanic to serve all your content makes sense.

However, in almost all circumstances you will receive better performance if you were to serve static files directly from something like `nginx`. This (in my opinioin) goes for **ANY Python framework** (or for that matter, **any framework**). Static files are generally best served directly.

As for whether your dynamic content should run through `gunicorn` before hitting Sanic ... again, [this is an option](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/deploying.html#running-via-gunicorn). I personally do not see a benefit for most projects. It is another layer on the stack, and does not add much to the mix. There may be some features that you get out of the box, so I would recommend you checking if there is something that the server would give you out of the box that Sanic does not.

Comment: @dmitry-bubnenkov, I just realized that I think you may be the same person who's question I answered on the forums. Let me know if I answered your question and whether you need any further help.